# Any way to create a multisig address from Bitcoin addresses (instead of public keys)?

Tags: bitcoind, multi-signature

Any way to create a multisig address from Bitcoin addresses (instead of public keys)?

If not, why not? What would the problem be?

EDITED - Thanks for the answers. This is for an application that generates multisig transactions with escrow for external users. Of course anyone who controls an address can find the public key, but that's probably beyond many casual users (or too much of an hassle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `OP_CHECKMULTISIG` only supports multiple pubkey not pubkeyhash (addresses).

Comment: So? `OP_CHECKSIG` only supports pubkeys, too.

Answer (score 2):

While you can't generate a multisig address directly from a number of non-multisig addresses, you can easily get their public key on a single call. In `bitcoin-core` you have to call `validateaddress` and then retrieve the `pubkey` field from the response, which is the hex value of the raw public key that you can then use to generate your multisig.

Comment: I don't think this works for addresses that aren't in your wallet.

Comment: @NickODell it doesn't but each party can get their public keys using their own wallets and then combine them to create a multisig address.

Comment: Oh, I see. Good point.

Comment: Yes, this only works for your addresses.

Comment: OK, so each party can find their public keys and send them to the party that creates the multisig address. Bu1 1. Finding the public key may be too complex for casual users, 2. I don't see how users of services like Circle (the majority of new users) can find their public keys.

Comment: Circle is a shared wallet so users don't have their own addresses to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, but there isn't really any code to do it automatically.

Instead of creating a scriptPubKey like

```
<pubkey 1> <pubkey 2> <pubkey 3> 2 OP_CHECKSIG
```

you'd make one like

```
OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <pubkeyhash 1> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_ROT
OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <pubkeyhash 2> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_ROT 
OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <pubkeyhash 3> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_ROT 2 OP_CHECKSIG
```

Also, the code of the receiver would need to change, in order to recognize the output as spendable.

It's probably much easier to get their public keys. If they've used their addresses on the network, you can look it up using `https://blockchain.info/q/pubkeyaddr/<addr>`

Example: https://blockchain.info/q/pubkeyaddr/1snowqQP5VmZgU47i5AWwz9fsgHQg94Fa

Or, you can use George Kimionis's method to decode addresses.

Comment: Thanks Nick, could you point me to George Kimionis's method to decode addresse?

Comment: That's just the answer below.

Comment: A problem is that many casual users don't know their public keys and are unable to find them, and others (e.g. Circle etc.) can't know them at all.

Comment: oops sorry I didn't see that

Comment: @NickODell Wow! Have you actually run this script? I'll give it a shot on testnet, bc as you know I love script stuff

Comment: @WizardOfOzzie I have not tested this. You should be able to spend it with a scripSig of `0 <sig> <sig> <key> <key <key>`, though.